# set value of form control inside a class

Tags: angular, typescript, form-control

how can I set value of value inside a class (part of the class values we got from a server)
[![typescript class][1]][1]

I need to set value of decisionStatusId, decisionStatusTypeName ans the structure describes below:

structure
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/rJ26Q.png

```
export interface ReviewRequestDecisionModel {
  decision?: DecisionModel | undefined;
}

export interface DecisionModel {
  decisionStatusTypeName?: string | undefined;
  decisionStatusId?: number | undefined;
  activityTypeId?: number | undefined;
  reasons?: ReviewDecisionReasonModel[] | undefined;
  reviewSumFile?: UploadedFile | undefined;
}
```

this way is not working:

```
 this.fg.get('requestDecisionModel').get('decision').setValue(newDecisionId);
```

my formGroup:

```
this.fg = this.fb.group({
  selectedType: null,
  quantityOfTrees: null,
  formId: null,
  requestDecisionModel: null,
  _decision: null,
  freeText: null,
  //decision?: DecisionModel | undefined;

}) as FormGroupTyped<FOTreesDetailsModel>;
```

Comment: It would be useful if you could paste the form control details too. However, if your form control is having the fields named by your DecisionModel properties, then you don't have 'decision' - you have 'decisionStatusId' and 'decisionStatusTypeName' and you can do a get/setValue on those fields, and after that do updateValueAndValidity.

Comment: @MishaMashina thanks, I edited the post, if I get\set value this way : `this.fg.get('decisionStatusId')` it is not in the right place

Comment: How about: `this.fg.get('decision').get('decisionStatusId').setValue(newDecisionId);` and then `this.fg.updateValueAndValidity()`?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you want to set only some values, for that use `patchValue`. If you intend to change all values use `setValue`. For that `this.fb.group` should also have `decisionStatusTypeName` and `decisionStatusId` - you could initialise them with `null`?

To set only some values, use patchValue:

```js
this.fb.patchValue({
  decisionStatusTypeName: '123', 
  decisionStatusId: 123
});
```

If those two controls are not present you should first add them:

```js
method() {
this.fb.addControl('decisionStatusTypeName', new FormControl(''));
this.fb.addControl('decisionStatusId', new FormControl(''));
}
```